# How to number all pages in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I don't know why, but the following code numbers only the first page and I'd need all the pages to be numbered. Is there anybody that can help me out?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,times}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\cfoot{}
\lfoot{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=2.1cm]{LogiMod.jpg}}% Right header
  \fancyhead[L]{\textbf{Vernieuwingsimpuls}\\
  \textbf{Innovational Research Incentives Scheme\\
Grant application form 2014} \\
\textit{Please refer to Explanatory Notes when completing this form}
}

}

\pagestyle{plain}

\author{}
\title{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Overview}
\newpage

\section{Second Section}
\newpage

\section{Third Section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

It is there, but it has fallen off the bottom of the page as your header is so large.  You should leave room for the header when setting the page size.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,times}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm,headheight=8ex,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=2.1cm]{example-image-a}}% Right header
\fancyhead[L]{\textbf{Vernieuwingsimpuls}\\
\textbf{Innovational Research Incentives Scheme\\
Grant application form 2014} \\
\textit{Please refer to Explanatory Notes when completing this form}}
\fancyfoot[L]{\thepage}}

\pagestyle{plain}
\author{}
\title{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Overview}
\newpage

\section{Second Section}
\newpage

\section{Third Section}

\end{document}
```