# How to include page numbers on all pages and not only on the first page of the chapter?

Tags: page-numbering, footer, missing

We are writing our thesis, and in the beginning we had page numbers on all pages. 
At some moment we only have page numbers appearing on the pages where the chapter starts. Unfortunately we noticed later, so we don't know at what stage it happened.

I thought the problem is with some combination of packages. We do have quite a lot. 
However, when looking into the questions, there is a similar one: 
    [How to number all pages in fancyhdr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150163/how-to-number-all-pages-in-fancyhdr)
and indeed, it could be that we have not sufficient space foreseen in the footer section.

```
\usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{a4wide}  
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{algorithmic} 
\usepackage{algorithm} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,positioning, arrows.meta}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{array}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\usepackage[includefoot]{geometry}
```

At this stage I tried to solve it by adding the `[includefoot]` in front of the geometry package. But still missing page numbers.

Also trying with following two options, did not solve the issue
`\usepackage[headheight=8ex,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}` 
nor `\cfoot{\thepage}`

```
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}

\newcommand{\nocontentsline}[3]{}
\newcommand{\tocless}[2]{\bgroup\let\addcontentsline=\nocontentsline#1{#2}\egroup}
\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}

\allowdisplaybreaks
\makeindex

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\input{Titelpagina.tex}

\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter

\input{Abstract.tex}

%ToC
\restoregeometry
\setcounter{equation}{1}
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

%content
\input{0GeneralIntroduction.tex}
\mainmatter
\input{1.1Part1.tex}
\input{1.2Part2.tex}

%Appendices
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{Appendix 1}
...
\end{appendices}

%Bibliography
\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{Bibfile.bib} 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\vfill

\end{document}
```

Except for the title page and bib-file the other files are filled with chapters and sections.

Comment: I continued my search, and found again reference to `\pagestyle{empty} ` that should not be used. I thought this was not the case.
However I found one in the table of content section. Changing that one to `\thispagestyle{empty}` solved the issue.

Comment: You can put  `\makeatletter \let\ps@plain=\ps@empty \makeatlother` in the preamble.